# Why ‘read’ doesn’t accept \0 as a delimiter in this example?

Tags: bash

Say we have a string with at least 2 newlines and we need to break it into three strings, first of which may contain newlines inside, but two following can’t.

```
$ echo -ne '1\n2\n3\n4\n5' |\
    sed -rn '1h; 2,$ H;  # Combine all strings in hold space
             ${g;        # hold space → pattern space
             s/^(.*)\n([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)$/\1\x00i\x00ii/g;
             p}' >/tmp/h

$ hexdump -C /tmp/h
00000000  31 0a 32 0a 33 00 69 00  69 69                    |1.2.3.i.ii|
0000000a
```

Now, as we can see with hexdump, the data are correct. However, if we put these strings to a read built-in, it doesn’t work as expected.

```
$ read -d $'\0' a b c < /tmp/h \
  && echo -e "---$a---\n+++$b+++\n===$c==="
---1---
+++2+++
===3===
```

The same with the actual command

```
$ read -d $'\0' a b c < <(echo -ne '1\n2\n3\n4\n5' |\
    sed -rn '1h; 2,$ H; 
    ${g;s/^(.*)\n([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)$/\1\x00i\x00ii/g;p}' );\
  echo -e "---$a---\n+++$b+++\n===$c==="
---1---
+++2+++
===3===
```

---

More fun: it doesn’t treat newline as a delimiter

```
echo ' - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - No delimiter'
unset a b c
read  a b c < <(seq 1 18 | sed -rn '4,+2 p')
echo -e "---${a:-not set}---\n---${b:-not set}---\n---${c:-not set}---"

echo ' - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - Delimiter is $ \n  '
unset a b c
read -d $'\n' a b c < <(seq 1 18 | sed -rn '4,+2 p')
echo -e "---${a:-not set}---\n---${b:-not set}---\n---${c:-not set}---"

echo ' - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - Delimiter is "$ \n"'
unset a b c
read "-d $'\n'" a b c < <(seq 1 18 | sed -rn '4,+2 p')
echo -e "---${a:-not set}---\n---${b:-not set}---\n---${c:-not set}---"

echo ' - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - Delimiter is $ \0 '
unset a b c
read -d $'\0' a b c < <(seq 1 18 | sed -rn '4,+2 p')
echo -e "---${a:-not set}---\n---${b:-not set}---\n---${c:-not set}---"
```

Output:

```
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - No delimiter
---4---
---not set---
---not set---
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - Delimiter is $ \n  
---4---
---not set---
---not set---
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - Delimiter is "$ \n"
---4---
---5---
---6---
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - Delimiter is $ \0 
---4---
---5---
---6---
```

---

No, I didn’t change IFS.

GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).

GNU sed version 4.2.1

Comment: We can speculate that the delimiter is stored as a null-terminated string, and that the `read` logic fails to distinguish between an uninitialized and an apparently empty value, and falls back to `IFS` splitting in both cases. Maybe submit a bug report?

Comment: It should work in bash. See this http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Comment: @aleks-daniel-jakimenko so is this a bug I should report on? //Also updated my post with newline tests

Comment: No, the problem is in your code. It seems like it is answered already ;)

Comment: FYI, `-d $'\0'` is **exactly** the same as `-d ''`, since the shell uses C (NUL-delimited) strings; this is also _why_ `-d ''` works, as the first (and only) byte of a 0-length string is its terminating delimiter. I tend to prefer this notation, to avoid implying to readers that the parser can represent things it cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-d` specifies what each "line" should be separated by. Each "line" is *then* split by the characters in IFS and put in the variables you specify. So if you do

```
read -d '' a b c <<< $'foo bar\nbaz\0next line'
printf 'a: %s\nb: %s\nc: %s' "$a" "$b" "$c"
```

the string is read up to the first NUL character, and then split according to IFS, resulting in:

```
a: foo
b: bar
c: baz
```

To split on NUL characters I use the following pattern:

```
IFS= read -r -d ''
```

This has been [extensively tested](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/examples/safe-find.sh) with things like file names containing newlines and other input.

If you want it to work with strings not ending with the terminator, you have to tack on `|| [ -n "$REPLY" ]` at the end.

In the case of your first test:

```
$ while IFS= read -d $'\0' value || [ -n "$value" ]; do echo ---$value---; done < /tmp/h
---1 2 3---
---i---
---ii---
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it’s all clear to me. This is a great answer, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Also, this was my mistake to not add finishing `\x00` to terminate the last string.